# Java Threading with CompletableFuture Threads

Tags: java, async-await, completable-future

I am trying to create `x` amount of parallel calls using the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` function with the below code:

```java
    ExecutorService customExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5,new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
        .setNameFormat("EXECUTOR-%d")
        .setThreadFactory(Executors.defaultThreadFactory())
        .build());

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<CompletableFuture<Customer>> graphQLCalls = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (String id : ids) {
      System.out.println(id);
      graphQLCalls.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
          () -> graphQLService.postGraphQLQuery(id), customExecutor));
    }

    CompletableFuture<?>[] futureResultArray = graphQLCalls.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]);
    CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureResultArray);
    combinedFuture.get();
    LOGGER.info("Completed multiple parallel calls: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

But I am getting the following time stamps for my threads:

```
2023-10-03 11:55:31.647  INFO 20776 --- [ ODS-EXECUTOR-1] a.RestClient: POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :78ms
2023-10-03 11:55:31.666  INFO 20776 --- [ ODS-EXECUTOR-2] a.RestClient: POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :97ms
2023-10-03 11:55:31.734  INFO 20776 --- [ ODS-EXECUTOR-0] a.RestClient: POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :165ms
2023-10-03 11:55:33.011  INFO 20776 --- [ ODS-EXECUTOR-3] a.RestClient: POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :1442ms
```

```
2023-10-03 13:41:15.164  INFO 20776 --- [EXECUTOR-0] c.RestClient  : POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :194ms
2023-10-03 13:41:15.330  INFO 20776 --- [EXECUTOR-2] c.RestClient  : POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :360ms
2023-10-03 13:41:18.008  INFO 20776 --- [EXECUTOR-1] c.RestClient  : POST DOWNSTREAM SUCCESS: Time Taken by Downstream System :3038ms
```

where the last request is always taking longer.

Any idea on why this is the case.

Comment: What does `graphQLService.postGraphQLQuery(id), customExecutor)` do?  Perhaps it is I/O bound, and must wait?

Comment: @AndrewS it calls a `RestTemplate.exchange()` function to post to a endpoint and get response. It is always the last call that is taking longer.

Comment: That’s a circular reasoning. The call that takes the longest time finishes last and is printed last, so it’s always the last that takes longer.

Comment: @Holger but I know for a fact that the calls should only be 100-300ms (including last call) since they are all same calls

Comment: There are no timing guarantees. It happens all the time that the same code has different execution times. Let garbage collection happen. Let there be a background process utilizing one of the CPU cores. We can’t tell you why one execution of a method we know nothing about occasionally takes more time. By the way, factory methods like `Lists.newArrayList()` were useful back in Java 5 when constructors had no type inference but nowadays, there is no advantage over `new ArrayList<>()`.